# Which clock to use?

Tags: management, overtime

My situation is as follows: Every morning I "clock" in be unlocking the building. I am typically first to arrive and thus it unlocks using my code. Everyone who follows in later does not have to unlock it. This clock is off by 10 minutes (late, so if I start at 9:00 it says 8:50). The last person out at night will also lock the building again with their own code (typically around 6PM).

Here is the problem - we are asked to report our activities during the day with accurate time. This is used for everything from pay to overtime. Recently I have been called out for "not reporting my time accurately". Since I will arrive and note my time based on the actual time, and when I happen to leave late as well.

However slightly more aggravating is I have also been called out based on actual time as well recently. My assumption being that if I was supposed to clock based on that clock then I would arrive 10 minutes later to be on time.

I have noted to the company owner that the time on the alarm is 10 minutes off but it does not seem like he plans on having it fixed anytime soon. Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? My only option that i see right now is to come in early every day and stay late every day as unpaid overtime to appease the schedule.

Comment: Ask in writing what clock should be used. If they are trying to get unpaid overtime and you are a non-exempt employee, that is most likely unlawful and you could take that up with the department of labor. In either case, follow the written instructions provided.

Comment: You might want to ask for the "unlocking clock" to be fixed instead of trying strange workarounds.

Comment: I'm finding your third paragraph difficult to understand. How is that different than the second paragraph? Are you being called out for following the time on the alarm clock?

Comment: @DavidK I was being called out for not using the actual time.This was essentially my problem being that I can't use the alarm clock, I can't use the actual time, and when I suggested getting the alarm fixed (months ago) nothing happened.

Comment: @MaskedMan Tried that two months ago. Was told "we have noted it down and will do what we can".

Comment: So follow-up on it, and keep pestering your manager until they "do what they can". :)

Comment: If manager doesnt want fix the clock, then just arrive 10 minutes late and leave 10 minute late to match the offset.

Comment: If you use the door with the same bad clock for both coming and going, why would you have to arrive early and leave late? If you're supposed to work 9 to 5 and the clock is 10 minutes early, then work 8:50 to 4:50 and management should be happy.

Comment: @Jay Which would be acceptable - if that was the case. Reread the question and I think you will find your answer is in the third paragraph. Because the only way to make management happy seems to be to follow all clocks, which would leave me 10 minutes early, and 10 minutes late.

Answer (score 3):

*A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure*

The broken clock doesn't even need to be fixed (it might require a technician, technicians need to be scheduled and paid), but the offset must be taken into account.

One way to do this is have a member of HR or your manager with you while you clock in / out in the middle of the day (lunch break maybe?), and write down the time from their own clock as well as your own.

Next reporting cycle use that as evidence against the bad clock, and ask the bean-counters to put on their green eyeshades and account for the offset.

Comment: I like the idea of getting it in writing. All of my meetings have been mostly off the record with nothing being written down, just a verbal warning. We are not large enough to have an HR and my managers arrive much later then I do generally. Also great quote!